# SQL-Server: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @locationids VARCHAR(8000)
SET @locationids='"PT11","PT12"' 
DECLARE @Sites VARCHAR(8000)      
DECLARE @tmpSites table (Data varchar(10))      
DECLARE @tmp table (Data varchar(max))      
      
SET @Sites = @locationids;      
      
INSERT INTO @tmp    
 SELECT @Sites    
    
;WITH tmp(DataItem, Data) AS (SELECT LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1), STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '') FROM @tmp UNION all SELECT LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1), STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '') FROM tmp WHERE Data > '')
```

---

Formatted for readability:

```
;WITH tmp ( DataItem, Data ) AS (
    SELECT
        LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
        STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
    FROM
        @tmp

    UNION all

    SELECT
        LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
        STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
    FROM
        tmp
    WHERE
        Data > ''
)
```

---

It shows following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: The CTE definition must be immediately followed by a statement that uses it. e.g. `WITH tmp AS (..) SELECT * FROM tmp
`

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name for table-variables and CTEs - `@tmp` and `tmp` represent different things.

Comment: It's unclear what is your query meant to accomplish. What is meant to do? What does the input data look like? What is the expected output? Also, why are you using SQL Server 2008R2 today?

Comment: @Dai - It is a sub optimal way of splitting strings using a recursive CTE. You can add `SELECT DataItem FROM tmp` to the end of their original code to see this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20dd949203080408f4dec19dddec37e5

Comment: Why assign the value `"PT11","PT12"` to `@locationids`, to the assign it to `@Sites` and *then* insert it into `@tmp`? Why not just `INSERT INTO @tmp (Data) VALUES ('"PT11","PT12"');`?

Comment: What are you actually doing with the `WITH` CTE? It's not followed by a consuming statement.

Comment: Your code has a semicolon, whose absence would trigger the error which you posted. The error message which you _should_ be getting is one complaining about the _end_ of the CTE where it isn't being used by another statement. Adding a statement, such as a select would alleviate all your errors

Comment: Your question/title is unclear or misleading. Can you explain what is your problem? Did you try to do what error message asked to do?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the compatibility level to a newer one (2017 - 140).
It worked out for me.